# Which Transaction isolation level should i use for read statement?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I need to INSERT a new record, using the MAX value of the city_id column plus one, in the newly inserted row. So if the MAX value is 14, the next inserted row's city_id column value should be 15.

In my code, I will get the max value for the city_id column, incremented it and then I am saving it. I am using a spring transaction for that code.

```
  private void saveCityDetail(final CityBO googleCityBO) {
    if (googleCityBO.getId() == null) {
      final Long cityId = cityMasterRepository.findMaxCityId();
      googleCityBO.setCityId(cityId + 1);
      googleCityBO.setActive(true);
    }
    cityMasterRepository.save(cityEntityBOMapper.convertCityBOToCityEntity(googleCityBO));
  }
```

I want to know the isolation level should be used so that the transaction can read the max count and take the read lock so that other transactions should wait for this transaction to complete.

Answer (score 0):

`SERIALIZABLE` is the only one guaranteeing "that other transactions should wait for this transaction to complete".

If the only action taken in the transaction is the read of one row, and the update of that same row, then no deadlocks can occur, and the normal retry loop will be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. But I am getting max(City_id) in the transaction and then inserting a new row with max+1. I just want to know that the serializable guaranty that another transaction has not even read max(city_id) (Read lock is still there or not )from the table until this transaction is committed.

Comment: There is no isolation level that prevents multiple transactions from *reading* the same record. Performance would be horrendous if that were the case.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Andreas.